# Vuejs - Element UI - Cannot close dialog with the cross

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm facing a little issue using `Vuejs 2.3` and `Element UI 1.3.1`  I would like to be able to close the dialog by clicking on the `X` but the event does not seem to be caught.

```
<div id="app">
  <el-dialog title="Shipping address" v-model="showDialog"
    @close="closeDialog()">
    <button @click='cond1 = false'>Close</button>
  </el-dialog>
</div>

var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        cond1: true,
        cond2: true,
        cond3: true,
      };
    },
    computed : {
        showDialog() {
        return this.cond1 && this.cond2 && this.cond3
        }
    },
    methods: {
        closeDialog() {
          alert('close event')}
    }
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zuL0uqy2/

It is working if I click on the `button` but not on the cross.
Could you explain to me why and what should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/dialog/src/component.vue#L118), all that happens when you click the close X in element ui is that it emits two events, `update:visible` and `visible-change`. You need to listen to one of these events in order to update your data appropriately to close the dialog. You could add a method like this

```
onVisible(isVisible){
    if (isVisible)
        return
    this.cond1 = false
}
```

and change your template accordingly.

```
<el-dialog title="Shipping address" v-model="showDialog"
    @close="closeDialog()" @visible-change="onVisible" >
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zuL0uqy2/1/).

It looks like their intention is that you take advantage of [sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier) being added back into Vue and use a `visible` attribute.

Comment: I missed that thank you. They indeed introduce back the `sync` but I still did not get it how to have the same behavior if I wish to use more that one `data-property`

Comment: Even in the documentation of `Element UI` they do not refer anymore to `v-model` but only `visible.sync`. Do you have any idea to achieve what you just did with the `visible.sync` attribute ? The `dialog` still need to show depending on (3) conditions and not only one.

Comment: @Leo not off the top of my head. You might try a computed with `set` in addition to `get`. Otherwise you can just listen to the events they fire and do what you want.